# How to move a document from SharePoint folder to local directory in a drive?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, folder

I know there is a workflow to move documents from one folder (or a library) to a different one inside the SharePoint based on their approval status or version number etc. But I want to move the document to a local folder in a drive (say P:) instead of a folder inside the sharepoint site.

Comment: Does this have to be real-time or batch?  Can you explain why you wish to do this?

Comment: Yeah, I want it to be real-time but if its not possible then batch solution will be good too... I want to detect the approval status of the document and if its approved then automatically move it to the shared drive

Comment: Why do You want to move files inside library, and don't use Views and filters to separate documents by it's status?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to happen in real time then you will need an event receiver.  If a small delay is acceptable then you can go with either a custom workflow or a Timer Job.

Lastly, you could simply create a PowerShell script that has the logic you need and attach it to a Scheduled Task in Windows.

Comment: Ok, when I tried to create a custom workflow, we will set the destination library right? In the window appeared only had sharepoint folders but not any local or shared drives.

Comment: Sorry, by "Custom Workflow" I meant a workflow created in Visual Studio, not Designer.